# Parameter count in numpy.fromfile has no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This question might be trivial but I really don't know how to fix it. Assume I generate a `numpy` array of size (4,3) using type `np.int64` followed by writing as binary file. The array looks like this:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

Now, suppose my goal is to read only the second row, `[ 4  5  6]`. This should work using the default [seek()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) function. To so so, I wrote the following:

```
import numpy as np
import os

# To write
X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
X = np.asarray(X, dtype=np.int64)
print("%s\n\n" % X)
X.astype(np.int64).tofile('test.dat')

# To read
f = open('test.dat', "rb")
n = 4
dim = 3
r = 1
f.seek((r*dim*8), os.SEEK_SET)

data = np.fromfile(f, count=(2*dim*8), dtype=np.int64).reshape(-1, dim)
print("The Reading data is:\n %s\n" % data)
```

However, I get the entire array although I only want `[ 4  5  6]`:

```
The Reading data is:
 [[ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

In `np.fromfile`, the parameter `count=(r*dim*8)` seems to have no effect!! Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong here!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only `[4 5 6]` (1 element with 3 items), your count should be your `dim` (i.e. 3)

```
data = np.fromfile(f, count=dim, dtype=np.int64).reshape(-1, dim)
```